# how to import informats (comma separated values) into sas

Tags: sas, informat

I have a data with commas in tab file and I have imported it the values were imported into sas as a char datatype with a comma values. 
like 23,1 53,2

I want to now convert these into numeric with either . or comma how do i do it? 
if I use

```
want=input(have,comma.);
informat want comma.;
format want comma.;
```

I get missing values., !

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean that `23,1` is the european-style `23.1`, correct?  You don't mean that `23,1` is actually two numbers, `23` and `1`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `NUMXw.d` informat to input numbers with commas as the decimal separator.

```
want = input(have,NUM4.1);
```

or just use that on the initial input statement and you don't have to convert it.

`NUMXw.d` also is a format, so you can use it to display the variable with a comma if that's how you are more comfortable viewing decimals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TRANWRD function to replace the comma with a period, then wrap this within an INPUT function to convert the new character value to numeric.

```
F2 = INPUT(TRANWRD(F1,',','.'),4.1);
```

Comment: Why would you use `TRANWRD`?  `TRANSLATE` is what's called for here, I would think.